# How to pass an object with attribute Value in python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I was working on the sorting but I'm not able to call the function with the specific way.

Basically, what I want to do is to create a function that **takes a list of object Node with attribute Value** and returns a list with the items from the original list stored into sublists. Items of the same value should be in the same sublist and sorted in descending order.

For continuing the code I want to know what should be the parameter of this.

```
def advanced_sort(<What will come here according to the call>):
```

> Function call:

```
advanced_sort([Node(1), Node(2), Node(1),Node(2)])
```

Can anyone please help me out with the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried:

advanced_sort(list=[Node(1), Node(2), Node(1),Node(2)])

This instantiates the Nodes as a list in the function.

`def advanced_sort(list=None):` <- as code
`advanced_sort(list=[Node(1), Node(2), Node(1),Node(2)])` <- as a call

Comment: I don't want a call specific as next time the function can be called something like advanced_sort([Node(3), Node(2), Node(1),Node(2)]) Then there will be a problem

Comment: Also, the Node is not defined.

Comment: Your function signature just needs to be `def advanced_sort(nodes):`

Comment: @quamrana I tried but seems this is not the way.

Comment: @UjjwalSinghBaghel It depends entirely on what you *do* with `nodes` in the body of `advanced_sort`. The signature simply doesn't care about the structure of each individual argument.

Comment: If the call is `advanced_sort([Node(1), Node(2), Node(1),Node(2)])`, then `advanced_sort` takes a single argument, which is intended to be a list (or possibly an arbitrary iterable value). What is *in* that list isn't reflected by the signature (ignoring type hints).

Comment: @chepner, Yeah you are right but still I have the same problem which is how should I use of the Node object in function parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`advanced_sort` takes a single argument: a list (or possibly an arbitrary iterable). As such, the signature only has one argument:

```
def advanced_sort(nodes):
```

Ignoring type hints, the signature does not and cannot reflect the internal structure of the single argument; it's *just* a name to refer to the passed value inside the body of the function.

Inside the body, you can write code that *assumes* that `nodes` is a list, and that further each element of the list is a `Node` instance, so that you can do things like assume each value as a `Value` attribute.

```
def advanced_sort(nodes):
    # If nodes is iterable, then x refers to a different
    # element of the iterable each time through the loop.
    for x in nodes:
        # If nodes is a list of Node instances, then
        # x is a Node instance, and thus you can access
        # its Value attribute in the normal fashion.
        print("Found value {}".format(x.Value))
```

Assuming a definition of `Node` like

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.Value = v
```

the above definition of `advanced_sort` will produce the following output:

```
>>> advanced_sort([Node(3), Node(2), Node(1),Node(2)])
Found value 1
Found value 2
Found value 3
Found value 4
```

Comment: I am bound to call the function the specific way as I mentioned
advanced_sort([Node(1), Node(2), Node(1),Node(2)])
                             or                           
advanced_sort([Node(3), Node(2), Node(1),Node(2)])

Comment: The function should take the Node object and its attributes from the call

Comment: That is exactly how you *do* call the function. `nodes` will refer to the single list value you provides. `[Node(1), Node(2), Node(1), Node(2)]` is a single value.

Comment: Man, I need to exactly call the function this way `advanced_sort([Node(3), Node(2), Node(1),Node(2)])`.
Don't ignore the **Node** term in a call.

Comment: I am *not* ignoring the `Node` terms. Have you actually read my answer? The variable `x` in the for loop will refer to each individual `Node` in the list.

Comment: Yeah, I've read and understood. But did you try to call your function my way? As how I'm bound to call it?

**When I do it ur way with my function call the name Node is not defined**

Comment: Everything I had was already mentioned on the ques, anyways you really are a lifesaver for me today +1

Comment: Your question had nothing to do with `advanced_sort`, whose definition (or at least signature) doesn't really rely on any particular definition of `Node`. It was basically, "how do I define a class whose instances have a `Value` attribute?".

Answer (score 1):

The argument is a single iterable object such as a list, a tuple, a set, ...

Then you iterate on the items as in chepner's response.

For exemple you can use a dictionary to group the Nodes by value:

```py
def advanced_sort(node_list): 
    ret = dict() 
    for node in node_list: 
        if node.value not in ret.keys(): 
            ret[node.value] = list() 
        ret[node.value].append(node)

     return [ret[value] for value in sorted(ret.keys(), reverse=True)] #descending order
```

```
advanced_sort([Node(3), Node(2), Node(1),Node(1)])
>>> [[Node(3)], [Node(2)], [Node(1),Node(1)]]
```

Comment: I know there are a lot type to work around, but the problem with my case is I'm bound to call the function this way only-
`advanced_sort([Node(3), Node(2), Node(1),Node(2)])`

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to make changes to the `Node` class? In that case, you could do something like this:

```
from functools import total_ordering


@total_ordering
class Node:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Node):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.value == other.value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Node):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.value < other.value

    def __str__(self):
        return f"({self.value})"


def main():

    from itertools import groupby


    nodes = [Node(1), Node(2), Node(1), Node(2)]
    nodes_sorted = sorted(nodes, reverse=True)
    nodes_sublists = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(nodes_sorted)]

    for sublist in nodes_sublists:
        print(*map(str, sublist))

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
(2) (2)
(1) (1)
```

Comment: The function call is specific can't change the way of call.